# JavaScript Error Uncaught ReferenceError: setEven is not defined at HTMLSpanElement.onclick

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am new to JavaScript and I have been reading everything I can on this website to fix this problem.  I was able to get this code to work if I put all the code in the .htm file.  If I use a .js file, it doesn't work.  I have used different jquery files to get it to work.  I have put the script.js script reference in the head, beginning of the body and the end of the body.  I am trying to get this code working as it is an example in my book and I think it will help me with the later chapters.  I want to use the commands as written so I understand what it happening.  I am at a loss as to why this will not working as written.  Notice the comments of the different attempts to get it to work.  The function in the .js file ...$(document).ready(function($) {...  was added later in an attempt fix the problem.

Any and all help will be appreciated.

.htm file

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

<html >  <!--type="text/javascript" -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    
    <title>Hour 7 Example 2</title>
        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" scr="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>   -->

        <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script> -->
        <!--<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-migrate-3.3.2.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script> -->
        <script type="text/javascript" scr="jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" scr="script.js"></script>
    
        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Hour0702.css" />
        
        
        <!--<   <script type="text/javascript">

              $(function() {
                  $("p").text("The DOM is now loaded and can be manipulated.");
              });
 
         </script> -->

     
</head>
<body>
    
    <span onclick="setEven()">Even</span>
    <span onclick="setOdd()">Odd</span>
    <span onclick="setFirst4()">First 4</span>
  
   
    <p class="label">Planets</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Mercury</li>
        <li>Venus</li>
        <li>Earth</li>
        <li>Mars</li>
        <li>Jupiter</li>
        <li>Saturn</li>
        <li>Uranus</li>
        <li>Neptune</li>
    </ul>
     
 
</body>
</html>
```

.js file

```
$(document).ready(function($) {

    function setEven() {
        $("li, span").css("font-weight", "");
        var $evenItems = $("li:even");
        $evenItems.css("font-weight", "bold");
        $("span:contains(Even)").css("font-weight", "bold");
        $(".label").html("Even");
    }

    function setOdd() {
        $("li, span").css("font-weight", "");
        var $oddItems = $("li:odd");
        $oddItems.css("font-weight", "bold");
        $("span:contains(Odd)").css("font-weight", "bold");
        $(".label").html("Odd");
    }

    function setFirst4() {
        $("li, span").css("font-weight", "");
        var $First4 = $("li:lt(4)");
        $First4.css("font-weight", "bold");
        $("span:contains('First 4')").css("font-weight", "bold");
        $(".label").html("First 4");
    }

});
```

Comment: because you defined it inside of document ready, it is not available globally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do 2 things, First their is spelling mistake of `src`, you wrote `scr` inside  `<script>` and second thing you need to write code of javascript out side  `document.ready()`

your HTML File

```
<!DOCTYPE html >

<html >  <!--type="text/javascript" -->
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    
    <title>Hour 7 Example 2</title>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    
        <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Hour0702.css" />
             
</head>
<body>
    
    <span onclick="setEven()">Even</span>
    <span onclick="setOdd()">Odd</span>
    <span onclick="setFirst4()">First 4</span>
  
   
    <p class="label">Planets</p>
    <ul>
        <li>Mercury</li>
        <li>Venus</li>
        <li>Earth</li>
        <li>Mars</li>
        <li>Jupiter</li>
        <li>Saturn</li>
        <li>Uranus</li>
        <li>Neptune</li>
    </ul>
     
 
</body>
</html>
```

Your script.js

```
    function setEven() {
        $("li, span").css("font-weight", "");
        var $evenItems = $("li:even");
        $evenItems.css("font-weight", "bold");
        $("span:contains(Even)").css("font-weight", "bold");
        $(".label").html("Even");
    }

    function setOdd() {
        $("li, span").css("font-weight", "");
        var $oddItems = $("li:odd");
        $oddItems.css("font-weight", "bold");
        $("span:contains(Odd)").css("font-weight", "bold");
        $(".label").html("Odd");
    }

    function setFirst4() {
        $("li, span").css("font-weight", "");
        var $First4 = $("li:lt(4)");
        $First4.css("font-weight", "bold");
        $("span:contains('First 4')").css("font-weight", "bold");
        $(".label").html("First 4");
    }
```

Comment: Those are commented statements as of now.  Are you saying I need to use those references instead of the jquery.min.js reference?  I originally had the code without the document.ready and it gave me the same error.  Thanks

Comment: you wrote good, but i can see 2 lines are not commented, 
` <script type="text/javascript" scr="jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <script type="text/javascript" scr="script.js"></script>
` here you wrote scr, it should be src, and inside your script,js file write entire code out side `document.ready()`

Comment: I have updated my answer, run the code and you will get it working. If it helps you, mark it as answer

Comment: I want to thank you for the answer.  Yes, correcting the scr to src got the code running.  It is so scary how easy it is for the code not to work and nothing tells you about your mis-spellings.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the scope of the function definitions **setEven**, **setOdd** and **setFirst4** these function are not globally defined are you are trying to access them globally

Here is the updated script

```
function setEven() {
    $("li, span").css("font-weight", "");
    var $evenItems = $("li:even");
    $evenItems.css("font-weight", "bold");
    $("span:contains(Even)").css("font-weight", "bold");
    $(".label").html("Even");
}

function setOdd() {
    $("li, span").css("font-weight", "");
    var $oddItems = $("li:odd");
    $oddItems.css("font-weight", "bold");
    $("span:contains(Odd)").css("font-weight", "bold");
    $(".label").html("Odd");
}

function setFirst4() {
    $("li, span").css("font-weight", "");
    var $First4 = $("li:lt(4)");
    $First4.css("font-weight", "bold");
    $("span:contains('First 4')").css("font-weight", "bold");
    $(".label").html("First 4");
}
```

just remove ${document}.ready event handler and define them globally.

Comment: I tried as above first, many times.  The ${document}.ready was added later and didn't make any difference.  Thanks